# How can I move a text overlay below image content for mobile?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build an overlay image. I want something like this:

[image]

The part where I am stuck is where the text should come below the image when the width changes.

```js
const images = ['https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?grayscale'];
let currentImageIndex = 0;

function changeImage(index) {
  currentImageIndex = index - 1;
  updateImage();
}

function updateImage() {
  const mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
  mainImage.src = images[currentImageIndex];
}

// Automatically change images every 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
setInterval(() => {
  currentImageIndex = (currentImageIndex + 1) % images.length;
  updateImage();
}, 5000);

// Initial image update
updateImage();
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-section {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  /* Added positioning */
}

#mainImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.text-section {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .text-section {
    order: 1;
    position: static;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-section">
      <img id="mainImage" src="image1.jpg" alt="Main Image">
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-section">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel justo vitae justo condimentum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="controller">
      <button onclick="changeImage(1)">1</button>
      <button onclick="changeImage(2)">2</button>
      <button onclick="changeImage(3)">3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The text _does_ drop below the image on screens under 600px. Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: the part in CSS responsible for this is in `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { ... }`